# How to get IP Address of client machine from Adobe Interactive forms?

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I would like to know how can i grab the IP address of Client machine using [SAP Interactive Forms by Adobe](http://www.sap.com/solution/lob/sales/software/interactive-forms/index.html)?

**UPDATE** : I tried the following script but it still doesn't work

```
<script contentType="application/x-javascript" src="http://l2.io/ip.js?var=myip" type="text/javascript"> 
data.subform.TextField1.rawValue = myip;</script>
```

Can someone update me on this?

Best Wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the printing programm passes the information into the form, you probably can't. The Adobe Document Service has not user session or context and does not know anything about the user - it doesn't even know the session language. You might be able to obtain some information using coding inside an interactive form that is executed on the client machine, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Thanks, Can you check the updated part? This might also give you an idea, I am now trying to execute http://l2.io/ip.js script and trying to read it on the client side while sending it back as a message to the server, But it still doesn't work. Any guidance in this regard will be great :)